# Find the null value of a Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I am building a AWS lambda function .net core.

The issue I am encountering is, when there is no data in the row / column of the datatable I still get a count of one, in turn `getData != null && getData.Count() > 0` defaults true and then throws a `NullRefrenceError` since the value is null when it goes to the loop, I have tried checking for multiple null types in datatable with them still defaulting to true.

Is there another way to check for nullable values, to avoid the assignment causing the error in a datatable column / row.

```
public object emailGets ( AType invoiceNum, ILambdaContext context )
        {
         Connection conn = new Connection();

         try 
         {
            string query = "SELECT QUERY";
            conn.getData(query);

                DataRow[] getData = conn.Dt.Select();


            if(getData != null && getData.Count() > 0)
            {

            foreach (var item in getData)
            {
              string yourItem = item.Field<String>("email").ToString();
            }
            return new userData { email = yourItem};
            }
             else 
            {

            return new userEmailAddress { email = null}; 
            }
            
        } catch ( Exception e )
         {
             throw e; 
         }

        }
    }

 public class userEmailAddress
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: a) Could you update the code to have explicit type declarations (instead of `var`) in the cases where the type isn't visible on the left hand side? b) Where are you getting the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Also, do you have [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) enabled in your project?

Comment: @devNull thanks for the reply, I went ahead and updated to strict typings, I seem to be getting the `NullReferenceError` in the foreach loop. I did not know I needed nullable reference types, since I read in the docs that `String` is a reference type and always nullable, nothing is needed.

Comment: You don't need nullable reference types enabled. But knowing if it is enabled narrows down the root cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToString()` will throw a `NullReferenceException` when the source is null. So when you do

```
string yourItem = item.Field<String>("email").ToString();
```

and the  `item.Field<String>("email")` part returns null, you'll get that exception.

Luckily, that `ToString()` call is redundant, so you can simply remove it and just have:

```
string yourItem = item.Field<String>("email");
```

Keep in mind that `yourItem` can now be null here.

Comment: What makes me wonder, is why the first conditional doesn't catch this. Yet it still allows it to go to the loop.